# Problem with upvote warning message

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, popup, warning-message

I don't know if this is the right way to bring it to notice, but when upvoting your own question (I know you can't) the warning message displayed is scrambled with special characters. Some problem with the translation maybe. I have attached a screenshot for reference.

[image: Warning message]